# In Polymer 1.0, how to find the state of polymer-button with toggles property?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a paper button given below:

```
<paper-button toggles id="saved" on-click="saveEntry"><iron-icon icon="icons:done"></iron-icon></paper-button>
```

Now, As this button toggles, how to know the state of the button after click? i.e if it's current state is clicked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property called `active` which you can use to see if the button is active or not. For instance:

```
_isButtonActive: function () {
    alert(this.$.saved.active);
}
```